# How can I "pause" database-entries?

Tags: php, mysql

Long story short ;)
Users can upload things to a database but only as long as the admin "allows" it...

For example:
after X minutes, there are no more uplads possible,
or, no more than Y uploads,
or, the admin clicks a link to "enable/disable" the upload-formular..

I cant really find a solution for that, im a beginner... any ideas?

Thanks already

Comment: You just have to keep track of all that information you listed. Is this limitation global or per-user?

Comment: if i get you right its global... also worth mentioning im afraid is, that the users dont have to sign up for the site, anyone can upload... guess that makes a huge difference? "Enabling/Disabling" the upload-formulat could be easiest...

Comment: Global would mean for the entire site - in other words, no one can upload anything if admin disables it. Did you mean that or do you just want to limit specific users?

Answer (score 0):

Usually I do this kind of job adding an ACL check inside the validation layer. I suppose you have a validation layer ( I use [Zend/Laminas input filter](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-inputfilter/intro/) ), so you should have this kind of check in your controller:

```
$inputFilter->setData($dataFromSomewhere);
$valid = $inputFilter->isValid();
if(!$valid) {
  throw new ValidationException(// Error from inputFilter here)
}
```

Your input filter configuration can have a custom filter with ACL instance ( I use [Zend/Laminas ACL](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-permissions-acl/advanced/) ), where you could add a rule with an assertion object ( check the link ) that checks if the current logged user can or cannot do the current API call.

Acl configuration can come from static file or dynamic database rules or both, configuration implementation depends on your needs.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your time and effort trying to help me out ;) Im just sorry to say that what you suggest is way to complicated for me, as im a real noob/beginner ;) i dont even know what you are talking about ;) sorry, but lots of thanks for your answer... :)